# How to use FuzzyWuzzy in Python to name match between two data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

I have df1 and df2. I want to use [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) to string match column A in df1 to column A in df2, and return an ID in column B of df2 based on a certain ratio match.

For example:

df1 looks like this:

---

Name

Sally sells Seashells

---

df2 looks like this:

---

Name | ID

Sally slls sshells | 28904

---

What I'm trying to do is compare everything in column A in df1 to find a match in column A in df2 and return the ID from column B in df2.

I would like to be able to set the criteria of the fuzzy ratio. For example: I only want it to return an ID if the ratio is above 50.

My current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
df1=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nkurdob\\Desktop\\Sheet1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nkurdob\\Desktop\\Sheet2.csv')


for i in range(len(df1)):
    em = df1['A'][i]
    test = fuzz.partial_ratio(em, df2['A']) 
    if test > 50:
        print df1['A'][i]==df2['B']
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks for the question, I have never used fuzzywuzzy before...

This is my take on your question.

Here I am trying to match the *name* column in 2 data frames, and I will only show results which have a greater than 50 score.

As I would then concat these results (or replace a column) I add blank values where there are no matches.... obviously you may or may not want to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

d1={1:'Tim','2':'Ted',3:'Sally',4:'Dick',5:'Ethel'}
d2={1:'Tam','2':'Tid',3:'Sally',4:'Dicky',5:'Aardvark'}

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index')
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2,orient='index')

df1.columns=['Name']
df2.columns=['Name']

def match(Col1,Col2):
    overall=[]
    for n in Col1:
        result=[(fuzz.partial_ratio(n, n2),n2) 
                for n2 in Col2 if fuzz.partial_ratio(n, n2)>50
               ]
        if len(result):
            result.sort()    
            print('result {}'.format(result))
            print("Best M={}".format(result[-1][1]))
            overall.append(result[-1][1])
        else:
            overall.append(" ")
    return overall

print(match(df1.Name,df2.Name))
```

When this is run you should see output like this.

```
result [(67, 'Tam'), (67, 'Tid')]
Best M=Tid
result [(67, 'Tid')]
Best M=Tid
result [(100, 'Sally')]
Best M=Sally
result [(100, 'Dicky')]
Best M=Dicky
['Tid', 'Tid', 'Sally', 'Dicky', ' ']
```

I am obviously only showing the intermediate results so I can demonstrate the value matching clause is working.

I then sort the list of tuples (as they were stored with score-then-value order), take the last one (you can reverse the sort and take the top value up to you), I then take the 2nd element ([1]) from the tuple.

This should work for any 2 string Columns, but I have not tested this.

Comment: Hey can you please try to answer this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68413792/how-to-sort-dataframe2-according-to-dataframe1-with-fuzzywuzzy