# how to sort dataframe2 according to dataframe1 with fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, sorting, fuzzywuzzy

I know this is old question in fact i have seen many links related to my question:

[Using fuzzywuzzy to create a column of matched results in the data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891131/using-fuzzywuzzy-to-create-a-column-of-matched-results-in-the-data-frame)

[How to compare a value in one dataframe to a column in another using fuzzywuzzy ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312265/how-to-compare-a-value-in-one-dataframe-to-a-column-in-another-using-fuzzywuzzy)

[What's the best way to use fuzzywuzzy to compare each value of a column with all the values of a separate dataframe's column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221743/whats-the-best-way-to-use-fuzzywuzzy-to-compare-each-value-of-a-column-with-all)

But i didnt get any proper solution for this

below is my code:

```
g = [{'column1': 'ryzen 5 5600'},{'column1':'ram 8 gb ddr4 3.2ghz'}, {'column2':'SSD 
                                     220gb'}, {'column3':'windows 10 prof'}, 
                            {'column2':'ryzen 5 3600'}, {'column1':'ram 16 gb ddr4'}]

df1=pd.read_excel('product1.xlsx', header=None, index_col=False)
s = []
for l in df1.values:
    l = ', '.join(l)
    s.append(l)

s = ', '.join(s)    

MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 30
guessed_word = [d for d in g if fuzz.token_set_ratio(s, list(d.values())[0]) >= 30]
```

product1 contains:

```
0   GB ddr4
1   HDD 256GB
2   SSD
3   ryzen 5
4   Win 10 Pro
```

guessed_word contains:

```
#gives good output

[{'column1': 'ryzen 5 5600'},
 {'column1': 'ram 8 gb ddr4 3.2ghz'}, 
 {'column2': 'SSD 220gb'}, 
 {'column3': 'windows 10 prof'}, 
 {'column2': 'ryzen 5 3600'}, 
 {'column1': 'ram 16 gb ddr4'}]
```

After appending to dataframe:

```
df3 = pd.Dataframe(guessed_word)
```

df3 contains:

```
column1                  column2          column3
     
ryzen 5 5600             SSD 220gb        windows 10 prof
ram 8 gb ddr4 3.2ghz     ryzen 5 3600
ram 16 gb ddr4
```

But i want following output:

```
#product1              column1                                column2          column3
0   GB ddr4            ram 8 gb ddr4 3.2ghz, ram 16 gb ddr4   NAN               NAN
1   HDD 256GB          NAN                                    NAN               NAN 
2   SSD                NAN                                    SSD 220gb               NAN
3   ryzen 5            ryzen 5 5600                           ryzen 5 3600      NAN
4   Win 10 Pro         NAN                                    NAN        windows 10 prof
```

is it possible to sort with df.sort_values or anything ?
i tried and none of that are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is kinda lengthy, but it does exactly what you are expecting.

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
#from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

class CustomMatcher:
    def add_space_before_numbers(self, text):
        return (re.sub(r'([0-9\.]+)', r' \1', text)).replace('  ', ' ')

    def add_space_before_numbers(self, text):
        return re.sub(r'([0-9\.]+)', r' \1', text)

    def add_space_after_numbers(self, text):
        return re.sub(r'([0-9\.]+)([^0-9\.])', r'\1 \2', text)

    def pad_spaces(self, text):
        result = self.add_space_before_numbers(text)
        result = self.add_space_after_numbers(result)
        return result.replace('  ', ' ')
        
    def partial_word_score(self, word1, word2):
        score = 0
        len1 = len(word1)
        len2 = len(word2)
        if len2 > len1:
            temp = word2
            word2 = [*word1]
            word1 = [*temp]
        else:
            word2 = [*word2]
            word1 = [*word1]

        for i, char in enumerate(word2):
            if word1[i] == char:
                score = score + 1
        if min(len1, len2) != 0:
            return (score*100) / min(len1, len2)
        else:
            return 0

    def match(self, comparand, target):
        len_c = len(comparand)
        len_t = len(target)
        comparand_words = self.pad_spaces(comparand.lower()).split(' ')
        target_words = self.pad_spaces(target.lower()).split(' ')

        complete_score = 0
        for t_word in target_words:
            for c_word in comparand_words:
                len1 = len(t_word)
                len2 = len(c_word)
                word_score = self.partial_word_score(t_word, c_word)\
                    * (min(len1, len2) / min(len_c, len_t))
                complete_score = complete_score + word_score
        return complete_score

search_array = [
    {'column1': 'ryzen 5 5600'},
    {'column1': 'ram 8 gb ddr4 3.2ghz'},
    {'column2': 'SSD 220gb'},
    {'column3': 'windows 10 prof'},
    {'column2': 'ryzen 5 3600'},
    {'column1': 'ram 16 gb ddr4'}
]

search_dict = {}
for entry in search_array:
    key = [*entry][0]
    value = entry[key]
    if key in [*search_dict]:
        search_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        search_dict[key] = [value]

filename = 'product1.xlsx'
products_sheet = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, index_col=False)
#word_set = ', '.join([x[0] for x in products_sheet.values.tolist()])
#MIN_MATCH_SCORE = 30
products_list = [x[0] for x in products_sheet.values.tolist()]
# Column #1
result_data = {}
result_data[filename.replace('.xlsx','')] = products_list

# Initialize columns #2-#n and populate it with placeholder values
columns = [*search_dict]
for column in columns:
    result_data[column]=list(range(products_list.__len__()))

for row_no, row in enumerate(products_list):
    for column in columns:
        matched_products_list=[]
        for product in search_dict[column]:
            print(f'Comparing {row} to {product} is:\t', end='')
            cm = CustomMatcher()
            matching_score = cm.match(row, product)
            if matching_score>50:
            #if fuzz.token_set_ratio(row, product)>25:
                print(matching_score, ' accepted')
                matched_products_list.append(product)
            else:
                print (matching_score, ' rejected')
        if (matched_products_list != []):
            result_data[column][row_no] = matched_products_list
        else:
            result_data[column][row_no] = 'NAN'

result_df = pd.DataFrame(data=result_data)
print(result_df)
```

Notes:

- I have created a `CustomMatcher` instead of using this `fuzzywuzzy` thing that is acting too crazy to have a meaningful threshold level to filter on. `CustomMatcher` is word-based in calculating the score, but letter-based on the comparison. It isolates numbers as words to be matched to after padding them with spaces. Those 50+ lines are easily accessible through the function `CustomMatcher.match(word1, word2)` I used `matching_score>50` as a reasonable sensitivity threshold for your application to match.
- You do not need to define a join between the entries in a single cell, instead, I used lists that ease access to every individual unit.
- The output is packed as a pandas data frame.

Thanks,

Comment: Many thanks once again !! I was in need of code like the code which is below the class CustomMatcher. when i replaced customer matcher with fuzz.token_set_ration()) also worked fine !! Thanks again buddy !